# List all files in a .tar.bz2, sorted by size

Tags: sorting, archive, tar, bz2

I use this command to list all files in an archive:

```
tar jtvf blah.tar.bz2
```

**How to list them sorted by size?** Or list only the biggest files (i.e. files bigger than, say, 10MB)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

list files, filter by size, print only size+space+path, and sort by size only, descending order:

On every machine I tested (back in 2016 when this answer was written: don't know... similar things but older, plus FreeBSD 8 probably; today: Artixlinux, Ubuntu 20.04, Ubuntu 22.04, CentOS 7, Devuan 3, Devuan 4), the output has 5 columns total, and 3rd is size, 5th is filename):

```
size=10485760
tar tvf blah.tar.bz2 \
    | awk -v size="$size" '$3 >= size {print $3" "$5}' \
    | sort -t' ' -k1,1nr
```

If you have whatever undefined OS one editor of this answer has, maybe you have the data in fields 5 and 9 instead, and then use:

```
size=10485760
tar tvf blah.tar.bz2 \
    | awk -v size="$size" '$5 >= size {print $5" "$9}' \
    | sort -t' ' -k1,1nr
```

Comment: awk -v size="$size" '$5 >= size {print $5" "$9}'

Comment: This will only work if your system doesn't print out dates as `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S`, otherwise you'll get an output like `10485760 17:51` with the size and time, due to awk seeing the space in between the date and time as another column. To fix this, just replace the first answer's `$5` with `$6` and you'll be good!